# Task return value, without Task<T> (async/await pattern)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I would like to write the following:

```
public string GetSomeValue()
{
    //directly return the value of the Method 'DoSomeHeavyWork'...
    var t = DoSomeHeavyWork();
    return t.Result;
}

public Task<string> DoSomeHeavyWork()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        // do some long working progress and return a string
        return "Hello World!";
    });
}
```

As you can see to return the result from the `DoSomeHeavyWork()` I have used the Task.Result property, which works okay, but according to researches this will block the Thread.

I would like to use the async/await pattern for this but cant seem to find how to do this.
If I did the same with async/await with my current knowledge I will always end up with this:

```
public async Task<string> GetSomeValue()
{
    //directly return the value of the Method 'DoSomeHeavyWork'...
    var t = DoSomeHeavyWork();
    return await t;
}

public Task<string> DoSomeHeavyWork()
{
    return Task.Run(() => {
        // do some long working progress and return a string
        return "Hello World!";
    });
}
```

This solution doesnt quite fit my needs because I want to return ONLY the string and not a `Task<string>`, how can this be achieved with async/await?

Comment: Why can't you return `Task<string>` because when you `await` it it returns a `string`. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't.

The entire point of `async` is to run code *asynchronously*. So the code returns a *promise* of a future `string` value, represented in .NET as `Task<string>`.

Think about it this way: if your code calls `public string GetSomeValue()`, then by the time the method returns, you *already have* a `string`. This is synchronous, by definition.

In your example, you have "heavy" work which I interpret to mean "CPU-bound". In that case, just do the work synchronously:

```
public string DoSomeHeavyWork()
{
  // do some long working progress and return a string
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

In general, APIs should not "lie"; if they are synchronous, then they should have a synchronous (non-`Task`-returning) signature.

**Edit:** As per your comment, the "heavy" work is a WCF call, which is I/O-bound, not CPU-bound.

In that case, the work is naturally asynchronous. Use asynchronous WCF methods (not `Task.Run`), and allow the asynchrony to grow through your codebase:

```
public async Task<string> GetSomeValueAsync()
{
  //directly return the value of the Method 'DoSomeHeavyWork'...
  var t = DoSomeHeavyWorkAsync();
  return await t;
}

public async Task<string> DoSomeHeavyWorkAsync()
{
  // Call asynchronous WCF client.
  await ...;
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: How would you solve my problem, with the `Task.Result` property or do you know of anything better? (Would be happy about code snippets if you know a better alternative)

Comment: In my real live example I am calling a WCF request to a client, and wanted to have a method thats running async to not block the client while server is calling the method (both Server/Client are WPF) should I than return the Task object instead of the resolved string/object?

Comment: I've edited my answer with my preferred solution: just do the work directly. And I've edited it again since the "heavy" work is a WCF request.

Comment: So its no issue if the WCF client implements the following interface:
`[OperationContract()]
Task<string> GetAccountValue(string accNr, string propertyName);` instead of a simple string/object?

Comment: Right; anything `Task`-returning is asynchronous, and if you consume it asynchronously (via `await`), it all works.

Comment: I just had fear that a task object cannot be a return value of a wcf method cause of serialization. Gonna try it on Monday, will come back to accept if every thing runs smoothly.

Comment: If it does try to serialize the task, that's a sign that WCF is out of date; as long as you're on .NET 4.5, WCF should recognize that `Task<T>` is just an asynchronous way of saying `T`.